# Is possible to remove "freeze" status of a property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, properties, freeze

If I freeze a property similar to something below, is it possible to undo the changes later without having to recreate the object?

```js
var obj = Object.freeze({foo:'can you add more properties later?', bee: {ahh: '?'}});

Object.defineProperty(obj.bee,'ehh',{value: 'can you change me later?'});
```

Comment: You've only frozen the outer object. `obj.bee` is still mutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when you freeze an object you're not able to change or add any property.

There is a function called [Seal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal), that might be what you're looking for.

> The Object.seal() method seals an object, preventing new properties
> from being added to it and marking all existing properties as
> non-configurable. Values of present properties can still be changed as
> long as they are writable.